# subscription erased

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have an RX code which is similar to the following:

```c
    static ISubject<Unit> m_events = new Subject<Unit>();
    private static EventLoopScheduler m_scheduler;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        m_scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler();
        m_events.ObserveOn(m_scheduler).Subscribe(onEvent);            
        foo();
    }

    static void onEvent(Unit p)
    { 
        // do something
    }

    static void foo()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            m_events.OnNext(Unit.Default);
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
```

Once in a few days the program stops entering onEvent method, and never recovers.
(even so the OnNext call keeps happening).

No dispose was called to the subscription.

I use rx-experimental 1.11111.

What could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that `OnException` is called, once this happens, the subscription ends.

Answer (score 1):

If `OnComplete` or `OnError` are raised, future `OnNext` values will be ignored.

As a side note, am I correct assuming your actual loop code does something more relevant that fire values on an interval? Otherwise you could simply use `Observable.Interval`

Answer (score 1):

Can you check using Rx v2.0 RC? We've solved a number of issues in EventLoopScheduler and ObserveOn.

Comment: Welcome to SO Bart - just thought I'd let you know that it's not good SO etiquette to leave comments in the form of answers. It would be better to just comment to the question. Please don't let me put you off - it's very nice to have you here.